# Как сравнить две строки и вывести количество ошибок в сравнении с эталоном?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть текстовое предложение (строка) эталон. Это предложение вводит пользователь в input и затем необходимо сравнить и найти количество ошибок по сравнению с эталоном (т.е ошибка в слове таком-то и итоговое количество ошибок) 
Сравниваю поэлементно как два массива (перебираю через цикл), но если допустим пользователь пропустил пробел в предложении, то дальше идет перекос в сравнении (undefined получается), а текст дальше правильный. Как лучше сравнивать предложения? Через регулярные выражения? Или есть еще варианты?

```
var ln1 = exampleMass.length;
var ln2 = keyRes.length;



for(var j = 0; j < ln1; ++j){
if (keyRes[j] !== exampleMass[j]){
//сравниваем элементы
resultObj.compare = 'найдено несовпадение: ' + keyRes[j];
console.log(resultObj);   
}
else{
console.log('Все совпало ');
}
};
```

Comment: Почитай про алгоритм расстояние редактирования. Оно как раз это и делает